# How to Get random position between two vectors?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make an object spawn between two vectors on the different x-axis, but it's not working.
Here is the script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEngine;

public class OrbSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject orb;
    private Vector3 minimum;
    private Vector3 maximum;
    private Transform trans;
    public float timeofspawning;
    public float spawnrate;
    private void Awake()
    {
        InvokeRepeating("Spawner", timeofspawning, spawnrate);
        minimum = new Vector3(-2, 6, 0);
        maximum = new Vector3(2, 6, 0);
    }
    void Update()
    {
        float x = Random.Range(minimum.x, maximum.x);
        float y = Random.Range(minimum.y, maximum.y);
        float z = Random.Range(minimum.z, maximum.z);
        trans.position = new Vector3(x, y, z);

    }
    public void Spawner()
    {
        Instantiate(this.orb, trans.position, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

The object just doesn't spawn. I changed the time of spawning and spawn rate to 0f, but still nothing. The problem is probably with `trans.position`, but I don't know how to fix it. If anyone can help, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If you have created the `trans` object just for this purpose, it is not necessary to change it in the update. It is enough to determine the position before the spawn to reduce the complexity of the code and increase the processing speed. Also, if you want the random location to be a line between these two vectors, use `Vector3.Lerp`. Otherwise, your formula is correct.

```cs
public void Spawner()
{
    Instantiate(this.orb, Vector3.Lerp(minimum, maximum, Random.value), Quaternion.identity);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure "orb" is a prefab**, the random position is working fine (sorta unoptimized though).
**To make a prefab drag a object from your hierarchy to your assets.**
You are also calculating a spawn position every frame, which is more expensive than calculating it when necessary. *I am unsure what is causing it to not spawn (I think it's a asset problem other than a code problem)*

***Here is some code*** for a flappy bird prototype spawn manager script I made:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
public class SpawnManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private GameObject pipePrefab;
    [SerializeField] private float spawnRate;
    [SerializeField] private float spawnPosX;


    //Create a custom struct and apply [Serializable] attribute to it
    [Serializable]
    public struct Range
    {
        public float min;
        public float max;
    }
    [SerializeField] private Range YRange;
 
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        InvokeRepeating("SpawnRandomPipe", 2, spawnRate);
    }


    private void SpawnRandomPipe()
    {
        float spawnPosY = 0;
        spawnPosY = UnityEngine.Random.Range(YRange.min, YRange.max);

        Vector3 spawnPos = new Vector3(spawnPosX, spawnPosY, 0);
        Quaternion spawnRotation = new Quaternion(0, 0, 0, 0);
        Instantiate(pipePrefab, spawnPos, spawnRotation);
    }
}
```

Did you look in the scene to see if it's spawning off-screen?

Here is the Unity Documentation for Instantiate:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html

Comment: Ok,thank you.The problem is not the prefab,if i change the trans.position to this.transform.position(referencing the empty game object position) it works,im going to try to find a different way of spawning a prefab on a random position between two vectors.

Comment: a position shouldn't be preventing the object from spawning. Are there any scripts destroying the object when offscreen? If so then it is probably being destroyed. Try moving the empty game object and see what happens. If not you can use Debug.log(var) to see